# Setting Java's GC options from in an application

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Can Java GC options, such as *MaxGCPauseMillis* (for the G1 garbage collector) be set from inside a Java application, or must they be set on the command line used to launch the application?

i.e. can I do any part of the following in code:

```
java -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=100 -jar app.jar
```

Comment: They should be startup parameters, I don't think you can set them with-in from application. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The purpose is to simplify launching an application.

Comment: You can create `.bat` or `.sh` file in this case.

Comment: Already done... my personal preference is an extra line of code in some class (probably one dedicated to this sort of stuff) than a more complicated .sh file.

Oh well.

Comment: You can always write a "quickie" mini-app that returns the setup parms for the real app.  It can even kick off the real app, though that can be a hair messy.

Comment: That's how this app will work in the future, and hence why I think it's cleaner to just do it inside the real app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, **this is not possible**. You cannot change the GC options of an already started VM.

Plus, I do not think that this is a good idea. **GC options should be independent from the source-code** because

- for the same application, **you may need different GC options** depending on VM-used, hardware used, etc.
- GC options are properties totally **orthogonal** to the functional needs of your application.

Modern applications (e.g. Eclipse) usually **use a property file** where you can specify the VM options, including GC tuning options, I think that this is a clean solution.

Comment: I had never heard of property files before (note: I don't know much about Java). I agree -- this is definitely a cleaner solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Certain (but very few) -XX options cloud be modified for running java process, using **jinfo -flag** command from JDK.

You can use -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal options to see list of all JVM XX options, ones that have {managable} type cloud be modified by **jinfo** at run-time.

But that probably bad idea. If you concerned about GC behavior in your application, you have to learn about GC. There are no magical XX options and no other shortcut ... unfortunately.